# ¿Cómo convertir un string a un tipo genérico T?

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy realizando una clase genérica donde agrego datos por consola a un array bidimensional. El problema surge al agregar los datos por consola ya que al ser una clase generica no se especifica el tipo de dato que se va a agregar

```
class Array2D<T>
{
    
    //Variables

    private T[,] datos;

    //Metodo Constructor

    public Array2D(int x, int y)
    {
        datos = new T[x, y];
    }

    // metodo agregar datos

    public void Agregar()
    {
        for (int f = 0; f < datos.GetLength(0); f++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < datos.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Introduce el dato ({f},{c}): ");

                datos[f, c] = T.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Error CS0119 T es parámetro de tipo que no es valida en el contexto indicado
            }
        }
    }

    //metodo imprimir array

    public void Imprimir()
    {
        for (int f = 0; f < datos.GetLength(0); f++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < datos.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                Console.Write(datos[f, c] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

He intentado hacer una conversión explicita (casting) pero no ha funcionado. Al intentar compilar me da el Error CS0119 T es parámetro de tipo que no es valida en el contexto indicado. Por otro lado, si quiero hacer un array de tipo string me encontraría con la misma problemática ya que no se puede convertir implícitamente del tipo string a T. ¿Qué podría hacer para solucionarlo? Gracias.

```
namespace ArrayBidimensional
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Array2D<int> array1 = new Array2D<int>(3, 3);

            array1.Agregar();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Empieza por incluir la definición de tu clase genérica a la pregunta?

Comment: Cual es la definición que estás usando? No termino de entender exactamente el problema

Comment: El error, en cuál línea está ocurriendo?

Comment: en esta linea: datos[f, c] = T.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  me indica Error CS0119 T es parámetro de tipo que no es valida en el contexto indicado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema radica en que no puedes de ninguna manera asegurar que el tipo genérico `T` tenga un método estático con el nombre de `Parse`. Es por ello que tu código no compila. El compilador no sabe cómo convertir un objeto de tipo `String` a un objeto de tipo `T` y no puede asegurar que `Parse` exista.

Para resolver esto, es necesario restringir el tipo `T` haciendo que implemente una interfaz que permita cambiar el tipo de `string` a `T`. Dado que estás trabajando con números, obliga al tipo T a implementar la interfaz [`IConvertible`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?view=net-6.0), la mayoría de los tipos numéricos la implementa. Luego usa [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-6.0#system-convert-changetype(system-object-system-type)) para convertir del tipo `string` al tipo `T`.

```
class Array2D<T> where T : IConvertible
{
    //Variables

    private T[,] datos;

    //Metodo Constructor

    public Array2D(int x, int y)
    {
        datos = new T[x, y];
    }

    // metodo agregar datos

    public void Agregar()
    {
        for (int f = 0; f < datos.GetLength(0); f++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < datos.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Introduce el dato ({f},{c}): ");

                datos[f, c] = (T) Convert.ChangeType(Console.ReadLine(), typeof(T));
            }
        }
    }

    //metodo imprimir array

    public void Imprimir()
    {
        for (int f = 0; f < datos.GetLength(0); f++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < datos.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                Console.Write(datos[f, c] + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

De cualquier forma, en mi opinión, no creo que la clase `Array2D<T>` deba tener la responsabilidad de leer sus propios datos en consola y parsearlos. Eso debería delegarse a otra clase externa.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. En este caso simplemente estaba practicando con clases genéricas. Tendré en cuenta lo de delegar a otra clase externa la lectura del array